# Confusion Matrix - Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, prediction, confusion-matrix

Working on my assignment today. I find that my logistic regression model is predicting 2161 instances correctly and 839 incorrectly. When I use this to calculate my confusion matrix my output is
[2161 0
0.  839]

my y_test comes from splitting the data into 70/30% for train and test. My
y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)

model being
model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = False, C = 1e12, solver = 'liblinear')

I says that I have no False Positives or False Negatives. This is how I am calculating it:
#Confusion Matrix
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_test)
print('Confusion Matrix: \n', confusion_matrix)

Any idea what I can be doing wrong to not have false values in my matrix? I am trying to predict if my target variable is T or F, a classification problem that's why using Log Reg. Also my data set does not have the target variable.

Thank you for any tip and any clarification or pointing me to a better direction.

Comment: If your "data set does not have the target variable", how did you train the model? Is not `y_test` the target variable? It should be, since you pass it as the first argument to `confusion_matrix` (assuming that's imported from `sklearn.metrics`). Also note that the output you cite means that all instances were classified correctly. This could indicate that `X_test` also includes the target variable, which should of course not be the case.

Comment: Thank you for your response! y is my target that I get from my complete dataset as y = df.target_var.values and X is everything else: X = df.drop('target_var', axis = 1)